# encoding when using FileStream and XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, encoding, filestream, xmlserializer

Given the code below, what encoding will test.xml be?

```
var filePath = @"C:\TEMP\test.xml";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    fileStream.SetLength(0);
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, "HELLO WORLD");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default StreamWriter uses UTF-8 Encoding, so your test.xml will be in UTF-8.
More details are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx)

Comment: how do you now the StreamWriter  is used in the code above?

Comment: Because XmlSerializer uses XmlTextWriter internally, which in turns creates instance of StreamWriter. You can see in sources. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,ef8c5504a875f43c